# Unable to access method in object literal

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, literals

In object literal we should be able to access the methods using `this.name`, but in my case below I'm using `this.init()` to trigger a method but gave me undefined function instead. However if I refer to `allTabAnimation.init()` it works, why is that ?

```
var allTabAnimation = {
    desktopClick: function (){
        $('.allForms .investorOptions .investorOptions-wrapper .select-options input+label').click(function (e){
            $this = $(this),
            $thisHookNumber  = $(this).data("hook"),
            $allTab = $(".tab-content"),
            $selectedTab  = $(".tab-content[data-hook="+$thisHookNumber+"]"),
            this.init(); // doesn't work
            // allTabAnimation.init(); // this work
        });
    },

init: function (){
    this.condition($selectedTab, $allTab);
},
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: Felix Kling's answer on the duplicate is spot on for what you can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store `this` in variable (or use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), or [`$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)), because in your case `this` refers to element not for parent object, like so

```
var allTabAnimation = {

    desktopClick: function() {
        var self = this;

        $('.allForms .investorOptions .investorOptions-wrapper .select-options input+label').click(function(e) {

            $this = $(this),
                $thisHookNumber = $(this).data("hook"),
                $allTab = $(".tab-content"),
                $selectedTab = $(".tab-content[data-hook=" + $thisHookNumber + "]")

            self.init();
        });
    },

    init: function() {
        this.condition($selectedTab, $allTab);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope (this) changes in the callback, thats why you need to declare it to a variable instead. Following conventions, you should use

```
var that = this;
```